# Implement Custom Functions in multiple pages in OfficeJS Excel add-in

Tags: office-js, excel-addins

We have developed Excel add-in with custom functions implemented as batching in page called Functions.Script.Url and Functions.Page.Url configured with manifest.

Now we want to have custom functions to write in more than one page like Functions.Script.Url1 and Functions.Script.Url2,...etc. to implement huge amount of functions. How to implement the same with manifest file configuration? Currently we could see the configuration for single custom function file as below.

Actual code:

```
<ExtensionPoint xsi:type="CustomFunctions">
    <Script>
      <SourceLocation resid="Functions.Script.Url"/>
    </Script>
    <Page>
      <SourceLocation resid="Functions.Page.Url"/>
    </Page>
    <Metadata>
      <SourceLocation resid="Functions.Metadata.Url"/>
    </Metadata>
    <Namespace resid="Functions.Namespace"/>
</ExtensionPoint>
```

Expected code: (Workaround what we tried based on Shared runtime)

**In manifest:**

```
 <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="CustomFunctions">
        <Script>
          <SourceLocation resid="Functions.Script.Url"/>
        </Script>
        <Script>
          <SourceLocation resid="Functions.Script.Url1"/>
        </Script>
        <Page>
          <SourceLocation resid="ContosoAddin.Url"/>
        </Page>
        <Metadata>
          <SourceLocation resid="Functions.Metadata.Url"/>
        </Metadata>
        <Namespace resid="Functions.Namespace"/>
    </ExtensionPoint>
```

**in web pack file**

```
   new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: "taskpane.html",
        template: "./src/taskpane/taskpane.html",
        chunks: ["polyfill", "taskpane", "functions","functions1"]
    }),
```

**In Taskpane.html**

```
 type="text/javascript" src="/dist/functions.js" 
 type="text/javascript" src="/dist/functions1.js"
```

Comment: May you please explain more about the purpose to use multiple pages for functions? Is it just to split one large file which contains huge amount of functions into several small piece of files which contains parts of the original function? If it is the case, you may can config [your addin to use a shared runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/configure-your-add-in-to-use-a-shared-runtime). In shared runtime case, the taskpane.html can reference multiple function.js files.

Comment: Thanks for the update xiaochun. The intension is to use separate function file for separate batching with number of custom functions to identify each function with respective batching. Also to reduce file size since we are getting "file size limit exceeds"  alert messages.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Muruga. I think you may can try to [config your addin to use a shared runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/configure-your-add-in-to-use-a-shared-runtime) then.

Comment: @xiaochun. I am trying to include one more functions1.ts file along with functions.ts file for split up pages...and can you confirm the workaround code what i have attached is that correct way to implement for multiple functions pages or let me please know if any wrong in implementation.

Comment: The code looks good except for the url of Functions Script url. You may can keep only one here as the real function.js files are referenced in Taskpane.html.